# Can we earn the same Winter Bash hats multiple times?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

I got an idea about earning multiple hats of same type. So I just want to know if it is possible to earn the same hat multiple times?

Example: **Boater**, this hat requires 40 votes in a day. So can we earn it for all days during Winter Bash when we reached 40 votes a day?

Comment: You mean multiple times on the same site? What's the purpose of this exactly? How will you use it?

Answer (score 8):

You already can earn the same hat multiple times on different sites

[image]

As you can see, I earned the Johnny hat on meta and on SharePoint.

What is not currently supported is earning the same hat multiple times on the same site. Anyway, why would you want that? only thing that comes to mind is to increase the hat count.... but that would then devaluate secret/rare hats in the global count.

Comment: Its just an idea/question raise in my mind, as we can get multipl same Badges on Stack for same event occurrences ( i.e: Yearling Badge ),So want to discuss on meta, so this is not just thing to increase the hat count.

Answer (score 2):

There is really not reason to be able to earn the same hat more than once. After all you only have one head you can't fit more than one hat on it(well apparently apart from `Johnny Three Hats` but that does not seem too comfy ;) ).

You can earn one and the same hat on different sites, but it will not result into having the same hat multiple times. You will simply get a list of all sites where you earned it.

Comment: Its just an idea i got, so want to discuss with you peoples, and why should not having multiple hats even if we have only one head. we do have one body still having multiple cloths and may be some of them are same! ;)